# Creating filter conditions based on list elements

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm interested in creating a filter, whose conditions depend on an input list. Specifically, I want to define the filter such that it checks whether a number is divisible by any number in my input list. So for a single element that would be:

```
my_filter a = filter (\x -> x `mod` a == 0)
```

basically I want to extend this such that if I have an input list, it would do the following:

```
my_filter [a,b] = filter (\x -> x `mod` a == 0 || x `mod` b == 0)
```

How can I define this filter recursively, such that each element of the list creates a new condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `or` function:

```
my_filter divisors = filter (\x -> or $ map ((0 ==) . (x `mod`)) divisors)
```

If you wanted to filter where all the values were divisors then you just have to change `or` to `and`.

Another way to do it would be

```
my_filter divisors = filter (\x -> any (== 0) $ map (x `mod`) divisors)
```

These are equivalent functions, just a little different style.

Comment: The `any` function was written exactly to wrap up this `or`/`map` combination! You just need to go whole hog instead of only putting half the `map` into the condition, as you did: ```any (\d -> x `mod` d == 0)```.